# Error 800004005 when trying to adjust chart axis range in vba

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I am trying to adjust my chart axis with a VBA function however i keep running into error 800004005.
When i google the error i can find a page that refers to the sheet security but there is no sheet security set in my workbook. I am using the following code

```
Sub test()

Dim Cht As ChartObject
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim min As Long
Dim max As Long

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Analyse")
Set Cht = ws.ChartObjects("Grafiek 1")


min = ws.Range("A14").Value
max = ws.Range("A7").Value

Cht.Chart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MinimumScale = min
Cht.Chart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MaximumScale = max

End Sub
```

Anyone know how to solve this problem?
When i skip through the code min and max both give values (min = 90, max = 140)

The error appears on line

```
Cht.Chart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MinimumScale = min
```

The litteral error text is (translated from dutch):
Error -2147467259 (800004005) during excecution:
Automationerror
Unspecified error

[image: eroor image]

Comment: Which lines gives the error, and what's the text of the error (not the number)?

Comment: Added in the OP

Comment: What type of chart is it?  That code works fine for me on a scatter plot.

Comment: Its a line chart, if i change xlCategory to xlValue its working

Comment: Line charts have "categorical" x-axes - you can't do this manually by double-clicking the axis either.  Try using a scatter plot instead.

Comment: Thanks always nice to learn something new :) Been grinding my teeth on this for several hours